# Обращение к нужному ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне обратиться к нужному ViewController для его настойки.

У меня есть первый  **TableView** с меню где каждый **cell**, должен вести на следующий *TableView*, как делать переход я разобрался и сделал это через **Storyboard ID** , но как взаимодействовать далее с этими View я не понимаю[image: Дерево View]

Answer (score 0):

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
  func moveToSecondController(animated: Bool) {

    //1
    guard let nextController = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController else { return }

    //2
    nextController.customTitle = "Hello"

    //3
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextController, animated: animated)
  }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
  var customTitle: String = ""
}
```

1. Проверяете существует ли данный контроллер.
2. Загружаете требуемые свойства для контроллера.
3. Переходите в требуемый контроллер.